# Rails gem rails3-jquery-autocomplete: How do I query multiple fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model, autocomplete

I'm using the `rails3-jquery-autocomplete` gem found here: http://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete

The instructions are clear for how to query a single attribute of a model and I am able to make that work without a problem.

My `Person` model has two attributes that I would like to combine and query, however. They are `first_name` and `last_name`. I would like to combine them into a pseudo-attribute called `full_name`. Currently, I receive this error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: full_name: SELECT     "people".* FROM       "people"  WHERE     (LOWER(full_name) LIKE 'cla%') ORDER BY  full_name ASC LIMIT 10):
```

There is no `full_name` attribute of the Person model, though I have the following method in the Person model file:

```
def full_name
  "#{self.first_name} #{self.last_name}"
end
```

How do I modify the Person model file so that calls to `full_name` queries the database to match a combination of `first_name` and `last_name`?

Comment: The maintained gem is [here](https://github.com/bigtunacan/rails-jquery-autocomplete)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your pseudo attribute works only on records already retrieved, but it has no bearing on searching for records.  Probably the easiest solution is a named [named scope](http://edgerails.info/articles/what-s-new-in-edge-rails/2010/02/23/the-skinny-on-scopes-formerly-named-scope/) like:

```
 scope :search_by_name, lambda { |q|
   (q ? where(["first_name LIKE ? or last_name LIKE ? or concat(first_name, ' ', last_name) like ?", '%'+ q + '%', '%'+ q + '%','%'+ q + '%' ])  : {})
 }
```

Thus, a call like:

```
Person.search_by_name(params[:q])
```

will return an appropriate result set.  It will also return all entries if no param was passed (or more specifically, this scope will add nothing extra), making it an easy drop-in for the index action.

Comment: Can anyone indicate how to integrate this with the autocomplete gem? (What should be the arguments for the `autocomplete` call in the controller? It doesn't appear to me that the `scopes` option will work for scopes that require parameters.)

Comment: that's quite useful when you think about it; thanks for this hint !

Comment: @JellicleCat
This scope trick makes the autocomplete gem partially useless. Actually, only the frontend html/css/js remains useful. If you want to integrate it to autocomplete, what you could do is manually create a route and a controller action that returns `Person.search_by_name(params[:term])`
But it's more tricky, because you have to reformat the response correctly : the retured JSON must look like `[{"id":"541ee2d953746106180e0000","label":"your_display_value","value":"your_value","extra_field":"extra_value"}]`

Comment: @JellicleCat, I have finally come up with some good integration. See my answer.

Answer (score 7):

Sadly, the scope method mentioned above didn't work for me. My solution was to simply overwrite the get_autocomplete_items method (formerly get_items).

For what it's worth, there is a MySQL function (other db's have it as well, but we're talking MySQL for the moment) that is better suited to the type of concatenation you're using:

```
def get_autocomplete_items(parameters)
  items = Contact.select("DISTINCT CONCAT_WS(' ', first_name, last_name) AS full_name, first_name, last_name").where(["CONCAT_WS(' ', first_name, last_name) LIKE ?", "%#{parameters[:term]}%"])
end
```

MySQL's CONCAT_WS() is intended to join strings together with some sort of separator and is ideal for full names.

This chunk of code basically says return the "first last" formatted names of contacts that match whatever the user is searching by when we pair up the database's contact records by a concatenated pairs of first and last names. I feel it's better than the SQL statement above since it does a full search that will match first AND/OR last name in one statement, not three OR statements.

Using this "hn sm" would match "John Smith" since indeed "hm sm" is LIKE "John Smith". Furthermore, it has the added benefit of also *returning* the concatenated first and last name of each contact. You may want the full record. If that's the case, remove the select() query from the line above. I personally had the need for the user to search for a name and have an autocomplete field return all possible matches, not the records.

I know this is a bit late, but I hope it helps someone else!

Comment: but following this approach the update of the hidden :id field doens't work anymore :-(    <%= f.hidden_field :project_id, :id => "real_project_id" %>
     <%= autocomplete_field_tag 'fake_project', '',
     autocomplete_project_name_hours_path, :update_elements => {:id => '#real_project_id' } %>
   <% else %>

Answer (score 4):

---

**Full implementation of multiple-field autocomplete :**

---

Following my comment, my solution to integrate into jquery-autocomplete was to have a custom implementation of the "internal" autocomplete.

**1. Query the database**

If you're using ActiveRecord, you can use DGM's solution for your named_scope

If you're using Mongoid, you can use this syntax instead:

```
scope :by_first_name, ->(regex){ 
    where(:first_name => /#{Regexp.escape(regex)}/i)
}
scope :by_last_name, ->(regex){
    where(:last_name => /#{Regexp.escape(regex)}/i)
}
scope :by_name, ->(regex){ 
    any_of([by_first_name(regex).selector, by_last_name(regex).selector])
}
```

**EDIT** : if you want a stronger autocomplete that can handle accents, matching parts of text, etc; you should try the mongoid text index. Credits to [the original answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37080486/2832282)

```
index(first_name: 'text', last_name: 'text')

scope :by_name, ->(str) {
  where(:$text => { :$search => str })
}
```

And don't forget to build the indexes after adding that `rake db:mongoid:create_indexes`

So you can basically do `User.by_name(something)`

**2. Create an autocomplete action in your controller**

Because the one provided by jquery-autocomplete... ain't gonna do what we want.

*Note that you'll have to convert the result to JSON so it can be used in the frontend jquery-autocomplete. For this I have chosen to use the gem ActiveModel::Serializer, but feel free to use something else if you prefer, and skip step 3*

In your controller :

```
def autocomplete
    @users = User.by_name(params[:term])
    render json: @users, root: false, each_serializer: AutocompleteSerializer
end
```

**3. Reformat the response**

Your serializer using the gem [activemodel](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/tree/0-9-stable):

*I provided the link to the 0.9 version, as the `master` mainpage doesn't contain the full documentation.*

```
class AutocompleteSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :label, :value

  def label
    object.name
    # Bonus : if you want a different name instead, you can define an 'autocomplete_name' method here or in your user model and use this implementation
    # object.respond_to?('autocomplete_name') ? object.autocomplete_name : object.name
  end

  def value
    object.name
  end
```

**4. Create a route for your autocompletion**

In your routes :

```
get '/users/autocomplete', to: 'users#autocomplete', as: 'autocomplete_user'
```

**5. Have fun in your views**

Finally in your views you can use the default syntax of jquery-rails, but remember to change the path !

```
<%= form_tag '' do
  autocomplete_field_tag 'Name', '', autocomplete_user_path, :id_element => "#{your_id}", class: "form-control"
end %>
```

RQ : I used some 2-level deep nested forms, so it was a bit tricky to get the right id element `your_id`. In my case I had to do somethig complicated, but most likely it will be simple for you. You can always have a look at the generated DOM to retrieve the field ID

Comment: That looks pretty slick. :)

Comment: Slick, @CyrilDD, but as indicated in my question, I'm using ActiveRecord, not Mongoid, so I need DGM's answer for the sticky wicket, the model implementation.

Comment: Yes, I mentionned this in the first step "query the database". For the rest, it doesn't matter whether you use ActiveRecord or Mongoid. I Just wrote this for the guys like me who were wondering why DGM syntax didn't work on mongoid :)

Comment: Excelent, i was looking for this for months, as i want to fully customize my searchs, for instance if i want to autocomplete for different attributes on a same model

Comment: I edited to show how to use case/accent insensitive autocomplete using Mongoid text index.

Answer (score 2):

This is a hack and I would very much like this function to be included in the gem but as slant said overwriting the get_autocomplete_items works as he wrote it but it will only return first_name and last_name from the model column. In order to restore functionality that frank blizzard asked for you also need to return the id of the row.

```
items = Contact.select("DISTINCT CONCAT_WS(' ', first_name, last_name) AS full_name, first_name, last_name, id").where(["CONCAT_WS(' ', first_name, last_name) LIKE ?", "%#{parameters[:term]}%"])
```

The difference between mine and slant's answer is id as the last argument of the select method. I know it is late but I hope it helps somebody in the future.

If you don't need the functionality of comparing your search string against the concatenated string and are trying to just do a query on three separate columns you can use this fork of the gem : git://github.com/slash4/rails3-jquery-autocomplete.git. Oh also that fork will only work with ActiveRecord which is probably why they didn't pull it.

Comment: Helpful, thanks. PostgreSQL alternative:  looks like Postgres 9.1 has `CONCAT_WS` but I'm on 8.4. Fortunately my fields are not NULLable so I can get away with `Person.select("first_name, last_name, id").where(["LOWER(first_name || ' ' || last_name) LIKE LOWER(?)", "%#{parameters[:term]}%"])`. Note the addition of `LOWER` to make it case-insensitive. I don't need the concatenated value in the `SELECT` clause because like the original question, I have a `def full_name` in my model that does concatenation once the record is found. All I need in my controller is `autocomplete :person, full_name`.

Answer (score 1):

To perform a case-insensitive search using @Cyril's method for `rails4-autocomplete`, I did a slight modification to the named scope @DGM provided

```
 scope :search_by_name, lambda { |q|
   q.downcase!
   (q ? where(["lower(first_name) LIKE ? or lower(last_name) LIKE ? or concat(lower(first_name), ' ', lower(last_name)) like ?", '%'+ q + '%', '%'+ q + '%','%'+ q + '%' ])  : {})
 }
```

This converts the record's entry to lowercase and also converts the search string to lowercase as it does the comparison

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the previous suggestions is to define a SQL view on the table holding first_name and last_name. Your SQL code (in SQLite) might look like:

```
CREATE VIEW Contacts AS
SELECT user.id, ( user.first_name || ' ' || users.last_name ) AS fullname
FROM persons;
```

Then define a model for the table:

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
    set_table_name "contacts"
end
```

You can now use rails3-jquery-autocomplete 'out-of-the box'.  So in your controller you would write:

```
autocomplete :contact, :fullname
```

In your view file you can simply write:

```
f.autocomplete_field :contact, autocomplete_contact_fullname_path
```

I will leave configuration of the route as an exercise for the reader :-).