# rails mongoid autocomplete a reference field showing another field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autocomplete, mongoid

Most likely similar questions have been asked, but weirdly I can't find it using those keywords...

Let's say you have a model `Actor` with a field `:name`. Now somewhere else there is a model `Movie` which `has_many :actors`. I'm trying to make a form where I can dynamically add some actors to a movie.

Using angularJS I would have used typeahead:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="actor_selected" placeholder="Add actor to movie" 
 typeahead="actor as actor.name for actor in actors">
```

Which basically shows and autocompletes by actor name, but internally saves the actor_id in `$scope.actor_selected`

How can i do that using rails-autocomplete plugin in an .erb file? The following isn't working/doing what I want :

```
<%= f.autocomplete_field :actor_id, movies_autocomplete_actor_name_path, class: "form-control" %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fast answer: using :id-element provided by the gem autocomplete.

Long answer :
Even with this, I couldn't find a way to do exactly what I wanted so I hed to reimplement the backend part.

I have described everything in the answer [I gave in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3866391/rails-gem-rails3-jquery-autocomplete-how-do-i-query-multiple-fields/26745180#26745180).