# Rails autocomplete for embedded documents on multiple fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autocomplete, mongoid, multiple-columns

I am using mongoid and I have a embedded structure that looks like this* :

```
class User
    field :first_name
    field :last_name

    embeds_one :administrateur
    embeds_many :customers
    embeds_one :contractor
```

now I want to be able to autocomplete a Customer (on both first and last name). I think I could first use a named scope on the User class to retrieve every matching user, but then :

- I can't come up with the good syntax to "autocomplete" on the first and last_name (I'm not using SQL, so the [answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3866391/rails-gem-rails3-jquery-autocomplete-how-do-i-query-multiple-fields) don't work)
- Once I have the list of users whose name match the autocomplete term, I have to get the corresponding embedded document(s).

So I believe this kind of code would work :

```
@customers = Array.new
User.by_name(params[:term]).each do |user|
    @customers << user.customers
end
```

I just need to implement the named scope `User.by_name`. Could you help with that ?

**The idea : a User can be an admin, a contractor, or can be a customer (multiple association, because people evolve in life, ya know :D). This structure of having one model that embeds others was selected to facilitate LDAP-based devise authentication.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax I came up with for mongoid

```
class User
    ...
    scope :by_first_name, ->(regex){ 
        where(:first_name => /#{Regexp.escape(regex)}/i)
    }
    scope :by_last_name, ->(regex){
        where(:last_name => /#{Regexp.escape(regex)}/i)
    }
    scope :by_name, ->(regex){ 
        any_of([by_first_name(regex).selector, by_last_name(regex).selector])
    }
```